# What does the matplotlib `hold` keyword argument do?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The `hold` argument appears in many plotting functions, for example `plt.fill_between`, `plt.arrow`, `plt.axhline` (for `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`).  I can't find any documentation on it, however.  [Docs seem to only state](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhspan):

> Additional kwargs: hold = [True|False] overrides default hold state

This is also a difficult keyword argument to google for...

Comment: @MattDMo the first result is http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html, which explains nothing.  But thanks for the super constructive comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be based on `MATLAB`'s default plotting, which requires `hold on` to be called in order to add more than one plot on the same graph. The default behaviour for `matplotlib` appears to be for this to be true, consider

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,np.pi*2,1000)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x),hold=True)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x)**2,hold=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

which plots both lines on the same graph. If hold is set to false, the next call to plot overwrite the previous. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,np.pi*2,1000)

plt.plot(x,np.sin(x),hold=True)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x)**2,hold=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or would Matplotlib have _much_ better served with a Pythonic object-oriented non-stateful API rather than the non-Pythonic MATLAB-like stateful API we got? Anybody? **Anybody?**

Comment: No Cecil, it is not just you. I couldn't support it more.... +100 to your comment. It's a very powerful library and able to produce excellent results, I must admit, but with a really upsetting documentation first, and a terrible API!! I learnt that "the hard way" and i'm sure i'm not alone.

I would be fine with the (sick) MATLAB-like API if the documentation would warn and clearly state the issues. But the documentation is just an unreadable pileup of API parameters... extremely difficult to browse around.

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hold#matplotlib.pyplot.hold):

> When hold is True, subsequent plot commands will be added to the current axes. When hold is False, the current axes and figure will be cleared on the next plot command

The value of hold determines if future plots are drawn over the previous one(s), or if the figure is cleared before drawing.